# Is it possible to enable/disable logging using cv?

Tags: logging, cv

Can the command line cv tool be used to enable/disable logging?

Comment: You can also disable logging via the API - see https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/28019/civi-5-9-db-error-no-such-table-cannot-disable-logging

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, but you have to use some bash magic. For disabling it is:

```
echo '{"logging":0}' | cv api Setting.create --in=json
```

(In case you forget, `cv help api` shows an example of the bash trick)

Comment: actually, I played around with it after creating this question and it can be done without any bash magic: `cv api setting.create logging=1` to enable, logging=0 to disable.